# What is a good interactive language parser for a C++ project?

Tags: c++, interactive

I'm working on a project in C++ that requires a command line interface to initiate commands in another area of the code base. In a single session there could be any number of commands sent through this CLI, all of the form `command-keyword [ param1 [ param2 [ ... [ paramN ] ] ] ]`.

I am looking for a library that:

- Parses keywords and parameters from a given command.
- Maintains maps of keywords to function pointers, keywords to minimum and maximum number of parameters, error messages, etc.
- Calls mapped functions when a command is formatted correctly, and fails gracefully when either the command is incorrectly formatted or the keyword does not exist.
- Is very lightweight with dependencies (I do not want to have to import the entirety of boost if I can help it).

I am sure this is very much a solved problem (and maybe I am just failing with my Google and SO searches), but I cannot seem to find a library that fits my needs.

Has anyone had luck using a certain library for this purpose?

tl;dr - I'm looking for a shell-like interface I can integrate into my own C++ project to manage interactive command parsing. Any good, lightweight resources out there?

Comment: How is it interactive if it is from command line - why not boost::program_option

Comment: Have you tried Matlab libs? Im sure there must be some

Comment: @AdrianCornish It is not from a single command on the command line. I am looking for an interactive shell within my program. Like when you run `mysql` or `php -a`. A prompt begins, you enter as much input as you want, the program does things as you give it commands.

Comment: @chpatton013 Then you are looking at lots and lots of code to do this - gettext lib may help which mysql can use

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık I'm not sure how Matlab libs would help me (or what they are, for that matter). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @AdrianCornish I understand that writing this framework on my own would be a very comprehensive project (one I do not want to undertake when I am certain there must exist a library that I could use already). That is why I am looking for such a resource that handles all that logic for me. Also, I am not sure how gettext lib would help me. It looks like a translation library to me (?)

Comment: @chpatton013 Totally get it - but for example you cannot ask a library to parse certain strings a certain way - maybe it can handle up-arrow to last command or even cursor editing of the command - but a generic solution will only give you so much functionality

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell

Comment: And I only need so much functionality. Ideally, navigable history and cursor-enabled editing would be great to have. But as far as base functionality goes, all I am looking for is something that will tokenize a given command, find an associated function, and pass it parameters. So really, a generic solution is all I really need. Do you know of one?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `readline`, non?

Comment: @KerrekSB GNU's readline seems like a great way to build the sort of tool I am looking for, however I do not want to have to make this tool. I am looking for one that has already been built.

Comment: `libreadline` comes pre-built with all Linux platforms, and you just need to install the development package to develop for it. There should be (pre-built) packages for Windows and Mac OSX as well.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want: it reads commands interactively like the console of a switch or router, it uses a tree structure to define commands & options. One problem: it uses a socket instead of stdin & stdout. You could modify it.
    https://github.com/dparrish/libcli